# how to add an image under my bootstrap and angular layout?

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4, frontend, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have the backgroundlogin.jpg image in the assets folder of my angular project, and I would like to know how I can place it under my layout, in the white part of the figure below, where the arrows are located:

[image]

below is the project's html and ccs codes:

login.component.html:

```
  <div class="jumbotron pt-5">
     <img class="center" src="../assets/images/full-banner1.jpg">
      <form class="form-signin jumbotron">
       <h2 class="form-signin-heading">LOGIN</h2>
       <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Usuário</label>
       <input name="email" [(ngModel)] = "user.username" type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
       <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Senha</label>
       <input name="password" [(ngModel)] = "user.password" type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
        <div class="checkbox">
         <label>
         <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me">Lembrar me
         </label>
        </div>
       <button class="btn btn-lg btn-color btn-block" (click)="validateLogin();" type="button">Entrar</button>
      </form>
     </div>
    <footer class="footer navbar-default" role="contentinfo">
     <div class="container">
      <p class="absolute">
       Criado por Douglas
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
                <!-- Add font awesome icons -->
                <a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
                <a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
                <a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram "></a>
              </p>
    </div>
 </footer>
```

login.component.css:

```
.center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
}
.form-signin {
  max-width: 330px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: black;
}
.form-signin .form-signin-heading,
.form-signin .checkbox {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: lightgray;
}
.jumbotron{
  margin-top: 0 auto;
  background-color: black;
}
.form-signin .checkbox {
  font-weight: 400;
  color: lightgray;
}
.form-signin .form-control {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.form-signin .form-control:focus {
  z-index: 2;
}
.form-signin input[type="email"] {
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  background-color: white;
}
.form-signin input[type="password"] {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  background-color: white;
}
.btn-color {
 color: black;
 background-color: white;
}
.form-signin-heading{
  text-align-last: center;
  color: lightgray;
}

/* Style all font awesome icons */
.fa {
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
/* Add a hover effect if you want */
.fa:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}
/* Facebook */
.fa-facebook {
  background: #3B5998;
  color: white;
}
/* Twitter */
.fa-twitter {
  background: #55ACEE;
  color: white;
}
.fa-instagram {
  background: rgb(216, 128, 182);
  color: white;
}
.footer{
  margin-top: 0;
  background:black;
}
```

the end result would look like this:

[image]

Comment: Do you want black color area or replace it also from the image?

Comment: I want the black part too, but it would be interesting to know how to do it both ways

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

**style.scss**

```
.bck-img {
  background-image: url(./assets/images/your_image.jpg);
  /* Full height */
  height: 100%;

  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

**login.component.ts**

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    const body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    body.classList.add('bck-img');
  }
```

...

```
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    const body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    body.classList.remove('bck-img');
  }
```

Make sure implement both OnInit& OnDestroylike this,
*export class LoginComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy { ... }*

If you want also remove black part try this.

```
.form-signin {
  max-width: 330px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Janitha Rasanga answer was right so i made the following change:

```
background-image: url(./assets/images/backgroundlogin.jpg);
```

for

```
background-image: url(/assets/images/backgroundlogin.jpg);
```